# How can I redirect user to unique URL based on the dropdown item selection in AMP?

Tags: javascript, html, amp-html

I have created two dependent dropdown lists using JSON file as shown below.
[two dropdown lists for Brand & Model selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyAQf.png)

On submit click currently redirects to "https://www.example.com/product-page" . I was trying to append URL slug at the end of it but couldn't figure out how.

I have all unique urls associated with each model name in JSON file but don't know how to redirect user based on model selection.

```
<section>
<div class="linked-dropdown-form">
  <form data-initialize-from-url
    id="formResetSample"
    class="field"
    action="https://www.example.com/product-page"
    method="get"
    target="_top"
    >
    <amp-list layout="fixed-height"
      height="25"
      src="/brands.json"
      binding="refresh"
      single-item
      items="."

      noloading>
      <template type="amp-mustache">
        <label for="BrandName">Brand:</label>
        <select id="BrandName"
          on="change: AMP.setState({
                                        ModelName: dropdown.brands.filter(x => x.BrandName == event.value)[0]
                                      })"
                                               
          data-allow-initialization>
          <option value>Choose a brand</option>
          {{#brands}}
            <option value="{{BrandName}}">{{BrandName}}</option>-
          {{/brands}}
        </select>
      </template>
      <div placeholder
        role="listitem">
        <label for="BrandName">Brand:</label>
        <select disabled>
          <option value>Choose a Brand</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </amp-list>
    <amp-list layout="fixed-height"
      height="25"
      [src]="ModelName || '/brands.json'"
      src="/brands.json"
      binding="refresh"
      single-item
      items="."
      noloading>
      <template type="amp-mustache">
        <label for="model">Model:</label>
        <select [disabled]="!ModelName"
        disabled
          id="model"
          on="change: AMP.setState({model: event.value})"
          
          
          data-allow-initialization>
          <option value>Choose a Model</option>
          {{#ModelName}}
            <option value="{{.}}">{{.}}</option>    
          {{/ModelName}}
        </select>
      </template>
    </amp-list>
    <amp-state id="dropdown"
      src="/brands.json"></amp-state>
    <button on="select:formResetSample.submit">
      Submit
    </button>
  </form>
</div>
</section>
```

This is the JSON file I am using

```
{
  "brands": [
    {
      "BrandName": "Milwaukee",
      "ModelName": [
        "2462-20",
        "2551-20",
        "2553-20",
        "2650-20",
        "2653-20",
        "2656-20",
        "2657-20",
        "2750-20",
        "2753-20",
        "2760-20",
        "2850-20",
        "2851-20",
        "2853-20",
        "M12FID-0"
      ],
      "ProductURL": [
        "https://www.example.com/product-page/example-for-milwaukee-2462-20",
        "https://www.example.com/product-page/example-for-milwaukee-2551-20",
        "https://www.example.com/product-page/example-for-milwaukee-2553-20",
        "https://www.example.com/product-page/2650-20-for-example",
        "https://www.example.com/product-page/mil",
        "https://www.example.com/product-page/2656-20-for-example",
        "https://www.example.com/product-page/example-for-milwaukee-2657-20",
        "https://www.example.com/product-page/example-for-milwaukee-2750-20",
        "https://www.example.com/product-page/example-for-milwaukee-2753-20",
        "https://www.example.com/product-page/example-for-milwaukee-2760-20",
        "https://www.example.com/product-page/2850-20-for-example",
        "https://www.example.com/product-page/example-for-milwaukee-2851-20",
        "https://www.example.com/product-page/example-for-milwaukee-2853-20",
        "https://www.example.com/product-page/m12fid-0-for-example"
      ]
    },
    {
      "BrandName": "Makita",
      "ModelName": [
        "BTD142",
        "DTD129RP",
        "DTD152",
        "DTD153",
        "DTD154",
        "LXDT04",
        "XDT08",
        "XDT11",
        "XDT13",
        "XDT14",
        "XDT15",
        "XDT16",
        "XST01Z"
      ],
      "ProductURL": [
        "https://www.example.com/product-page/btd142-for-example",
        "https://www.example.com/product-page/dtd129rp-for-example",
        "https://www.example.com/product-page/dtd152z-for-example",
        "https://www.example.com/product-page/dtd153z-for-example",
        "https://www.example.com/product-page/dtd154-for-example",
        "https://www.example.com/product-page/example-for-makita-lxdt04",
        "https://www.example.com/product-page/xdt08-for-example",
        "https://www.example.com/product-page/example-for-makita-11",
        "https://www.example.com/product-page/example-for-makita-13",
        "https://www.example.com/product-page/example-for-makita-14",
        "https://www.example.com/product-page/example-for-makita-15",
        "https://www.example.com/product-page/xdt16-for-example",
        "https://www.example.com/product-page/xst01z-for-example"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Each model name is associated with unique URL.

Comment: Thank you for the example. However, I don't exactly understand the question. Are you having a problem using `amp-mustache` `partials` where you want to map the product URL to an item? Or something else? Perhaps if you show the result you want, we can backtrack.

Comment: Example of a partial: `{{link}}'>{{title.rendered}}`

Comment: @JayGray Yes, I want to map dropdown item to product url. For example if user selects "BTD142" from Model dropdown list and then click on submit then user should be redirected to "https://www.example.com/product-page/btd142-for-example" this Product URL.

Comment: OK, use a variation of the partial I show above. Documentation: https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html

Comment: @JayGray I couldn't understand it. What needs to be changed here? This is the code - 

`<template type="amp-mustache">
<label for="model">Model:</label>
<select [disabled]="!ModelName"
disabled
id="model"
on="change: AMP.setState({model: event.value})"
name="q"
data-allow-initialization>
<option value>Choose a Model</option>
{{#ModelName}}
<option value="{{.}}">{{.}}</option>    
{{/ModelName}}
</select>
</template> `

Comment: @JayGray Sorry for the bad formatting of code. I'm new on Stackoverflow. Couldn't figure it out yet.

Comment: if i understand your issue correctly, you are formatting separate properties. The logical structure is like this: `<a href='{{link}}'>{{title.rendered}}</a>`. That would produce a structure like this: `'https://www.example.com/product-page/m12fid-0-for-example' > 'M12FID-0'`

Comment: In my code where shall I replace / add  <a> tag which you shared above?

Comment: @JayGray Here is the live page - https://walink.online/driverback-landing-page.html

This is the JSON file - https://walink.online/brands.json

You can see two drop down lists in third section on the page. I want to redirect user to Product URL associated to selected model from second dropdown. I hope this gives you more clarity. I couldn't understand where to use <a href='{{link}}'>{{title.rendered}}</a>